# Find all rows that are NOT in a date range using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date, range, autofilter

I'm teaching myself VBA by writing macros for a report that I process weekly. In this report, I have a large amount of data (~4000 rows) that I need to filter by date. My goal is to get rid of any rows that have a start date that is not within the last week. I wrote the following function to show only the data I want to keep, but then got stuck when I realized that I wanted to get rid of all the data that is NOT shown.

```
Sub LimitDates()

'Define date variables
Dim today As Date
Dim strDate As Date
Dim endDate As Date
Dim dateArray(6) As Date
today = Date
strDate = DateAdd("d", -7, today)
endDate = DateAdd("d", -1, today)
dateArray(0) = strDate
dateArray(1) = strDate + 1
dateArray(2) = strDate + 2
dateArray(3) = strDate + 3
dateArray(4) = strDate + 4
dateArray(5) = strDate + 5
dateArray(6) = strDate + 6

'Define Row Count
originalRowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).Row

'Filters to only relevent dates
Range("A1:I1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(RowSize:=originalRowCount, _
    ColumnSize:=9).AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:= xlFilterValues, _
    Criteria2:=Array(2, dateArray(0), 2, dateArray(1), 2, dateArray(2), _
    2, dateArray(3), 2, dateArray(4), 2, dateArray(5), 2, dateArray(6))

End Sub
```

I'm sure there area  lot of ways to make the above code better, but my question is: Instead of filtering the "good" dates, how to I filter the "bad" dates (everything before and after my date range)?*

Comment: a much easier way to filter what you wanted is ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(RowSize:=originalRowCount, ColumnSize:=9).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastWeek, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim today As Date
Dim strDate As Date
Dim endDate As Date
today = Date
strDate = DateAdd("d", -7, today)
endDate = DateAdd("d", -1, today)


'Define Row Count
originalRowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).Row

'Filters to only relevent dates
Range("A1:I1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(RowSize:=originalRowCount, _
    ColumnSize:=9).AutoFilter Field:=5, _
        Criteria1:="<" & strDate, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=">" & endDate
```

Use less than Or greater then the date you want as criteria.